# How to use "Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition by Oracle" image in Microsoft Azure

Tags: database, azure, oracle12c

I created a new "Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition by Oracle" instance in azure instance.

I am able to login to the instance using the username and password that i provided while creating the instance in portal.azure.com.

Now how do i start using this as my DB server for my application. How do i create my first database on this ?

- Looks like oracle is installed. I did "**sudo su oracle**" and i was able to switch to oracle user.
- Oracle is installed @ /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

But i could not find the DB name or the port information.  The portal also did not define any inbound endpoint for this server.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn439775.aspx) might be helpful.

Comment: no, the link is about the windows vm, not the linux vm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The database is already install in

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
```

You should do all the following as the oracle user:

```
su - oracle
```

**Starting Oracle**

Set up some envirnoment varaibles, e.g. in a .bashrc file. (do this
also for every user who will use the database client)

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

Start the listener:

```
lsnrctl start
```

now you have to create a initoracle.ora file. there is a template
for that called init.ora, you only have to replace 
in it:

```
cd /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/dbs
sed -e 's=<ORACLE_BASE>=/u01/app/oracle=' init.ora > initoracle.ora
```

also the audit trail directory is missing:

```
mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump
```

how you are ready to start the database:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
```

**Creating a Database**

If you log in to your machine with ssh -X you can use X-Forwarding
to use programs with GUIS.  The program for creating databases is dbca:

```
dbca
```

You will need to decide on:

1. a database name = the SID name (in the example below: cdb1)
2. the name for the pluggable database (in the example below: pdb1)
3. a password (in the example below: OraPasswd1)

There should also be a way to do this on the command line only,

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase \
  -templateName General_Purpose.dbc \
  -gdbname cdb1 -sid cdb1 -responseFile NO_VALUE \
  -characterSet AL32UTF8 \
  -sysPassword OraPasswd1 \
  -systemPassword OraPasswd1 \
  -createAsContainerDatabase true \
  -numberOfPDBs 1 \
  -pdbName pdb1 \
  -pdbAdminPassword OraPasswd1 \
  -databaseType MULTIPURPOSE \
  -automaticMemoryManagement false \
  -storageType FS \
  -ignorePreReqs
```

The sysdba should now be able to see the database:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> SELECT name, open_mode FROM v$pdbs;

no rows selected
```

(Based on [this oracle-base article](http://oracle-base.com/articles/vm/installation-of-an-oracle-database-on-azure.php), adapted for pre-installed oracle)

Comment: I had to use `export ORACLE_SID=cdb1` as the `dbca` created a database with that name. Then the `startup` will pick up the `spfilecdb1.ora` that is created by that command.